# Weak entity without foreign key

Tags: database

Quoting from Wikipedia

> In a relational database, a weak entity is an entity that cannot be uniquely identified by its attributes alone; therefore, it must use a foreign key in conjunction with its attributes to create a primary key. The foreign key is typically a primary key of an entity it is related to.

What happen if an entity does not have foreign key and primary key , but have super key ? Is it still considered weak entity or not ? Or it is not allowed ?

Example :
An entity consisting only two attributes : first name and last name
These two attributes cannot be the primary key since people can have the same first name or last name , but they can't have both the same first name and the same last name, thus making it a super key.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, it's still weak because people can share both last name and first name. This shows it still week. If to combination of these columns were unique, you could ave call it a primary key, as far as a pk is not necessarily a unique column.
And, to answer your question, to problem of this week entity is that your requests might be wrong or lead to issues, as you have to way to characterize your rows and retrieve exactly what you want. At some point, you can deal with that, if you know you can anticipate, but within a bigger database it might be complicated to develop complex relationships.